# How to automatically save plotly images of type "surface" in R (webGL issue)

Tags: r, plot, 3d, save, plotly

this is my first question within stackoverflow and I want to thank for the useful hints and solutions helping me out so many times before! But since a few weeks I have an issue, which I couldn´t solve and as well I couldn´t find any solution within the www. I´m working with measured 3D data and trying to set up a code for imaging the data. Therefor I´m using the package plotly so far. After some time I get it worked and the result is okay for me. Next I implemented it within a loop because there are several measured samples. For documentation matters I need to store an image of each sample and that´s not working in an automated way. At the moment the loop runs well and within RStudio there is the subwindow for the 3d-Plotly-Viewer. I need to store each sample manually and this takes a lot of time. So I tried to automate it, but without success. The problem is shown by the simple code below:

```
library(plotly)
zz <- data.frame(c(0,0,0,0,0),c(0.1,.2,.4,.2,.1),c(0.2,.4,.8,.4,.2),c(0.1,.2,.4,.2,.1),c(0,0,0,0,0))
zz <- cbind(t(zz),rep(NA,length(zz[,1])))
xx <- rep(seq(-1,1.5,.5),5)
print(plot_ly(z=zz,x=xx, type="surface"))

# My simple way, which doesn´t work.
# Storing in the working directory
export(p = last_plot(), file = "plotly.png")
```

The result of implementing this in the loop is an image without the surface like shown in the viewer (the scale bar is shown?!)
[image: Result image]
Additionally there is a text hint "WebGl is not supported by your browser - visit http://get.webgl.org for more info". Visiting this pages leads to the information, that my browser supports WebGL (Mozilla Firefox).

My suggestions: While exporting with "export" a html-file appears for a short time within the working directory. It is deleted after some seconds right before the image-file appears. I suggest this is in matter of using the webshot-package (or something connected to that). I stored a copy of the html-file while processing and opened it in my browser. It is just an empty window with the toolbar of plotly appearing in the right upper corner (though webGL seems to work at the browser). Maybe there are any configurations disabled within the webshot package? Could it be a matter of rights (I´m not the administrator) or is there even a bug with the graphic card (integrated Intel® HD-Grafik 4600)? I´m fishing in murky waters..

Edit:
OS: Win7 Professional SP1
RStudio: Version 0.99.902 (Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) rstudio Safari/538.1 Qt/5.4.1)
Browser: Firefox Quantum 57.0 (32-Bit)

Is there any idea how to solve that? I would like to automatically save an image out of the plotly-viewer. Any solutions are appreciate!

Best regards
Stefan

Comment: Please add some information to your question. Which browser and version are you using? Are you using RStudio? Which OS?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, i edited the post. Any other informations needed?

Comment: Try updating your RStudio to the latest version and try opening https://plot.ly/python/webgl-vs-svg/ in your browser. If you can open the link, you know your computer is capable in general to handle Plotly and WebGl.

Comment: @S. Rothe do you need it to be interactive? or a plain 3D plot works for you because saving 3D plots in plotly is a pain. Also do you have `PhantomJS` install and updated because it is required.

Comment: Hello again and thanks for your suggestions! I figured out the linked webpage by @Maximilian Peters. And my browser should be able to handle plotly and webGL. It shows all graphs, even if it takes very long for the second one. Unfortunately I couldnt update RStudie due to missing rights. But I checked my code at another system and the problem still appears. It´s Win10 with updated RStudio and FF.

Comment: @AlejandroAndrade: I don´t need really, but sometimes a data point is missing or there are other irregularities. And therefor it´s quite simple to stick at the viewer. And the image is just for documentation matters. So it would also work to code something else, but i hoped it will work anyway with the existing code. As i wrote before i didn´t have the right for installing etc. so i figured out if there is any change with installed PhantomJS. There isn´t. Still the same. Where i need the PhantomJS for? I just unzip and started the exe-file. Is there anything else to do? Thanks until now!

Answer (score 0):

I tried your example and i do not get the same error as you get. `PhantomJS` is needed so it R can "take a printscreen" of the plot being plotted with `plotly` and i think it needs other packages. This work for me, it might work in your computer but as I said in the comment exporting 3D plotly plots is a pain (you'll see why):

```
library(plotly)
zz <- data.frame(c(0,0,0,0,0),c(0.1,.2,.4,.2,.1),c(0.2,.4,.8,.4,.2),c(0.1,.2,.4,.2,.1),c(0,0,0,0,0))
zz <- cbind(t(zz),rep(NA,length(zz[,1])))
xx <- rep(seq(-1,1.5,.5),5)
print(plot_ly(z=zz,x=xx, type="surface"))

if (requireNamespace("RSelenium")) {
  rD <- RSelenium::rsDriver(browser = "chrome")
  export(last_plot(), "plot.png", rD)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello again and first thanks for your advice. I played around according your adapted code. But unfortunately I still have issues on saving an image.

What I done yet at my **private** system (to exclude permission issues, Win10, updated Firefox-Browser as well as Chrome, latest RStudio):
- Installed "webshot" and "RSelenium" packages
- Installed PhantomJS on system.
- Adapting code according to @Alejandro Andrade

First it takes a while loading some stuff and breaks up with an error. But it already opens a chrome window. It left empty with "data;" in the adress bar. I switched the linked browser to firefox, instead of chrome. Additionally I provide a specific port in the RSelenium call. Mention that I´m totally not into that package, but it prompts error, when not changing the port --> "port XXXX still open". Changing the browser does not lead to success either. See the error code shown by using "chrome" from RStudio-Output below. Is there any suggestion what I am missing? Maybe my data is the problem?!

BTW: I figured out again why I am using plotly while trying to get a comparable image with persp3d from "rgl" package. There the y- and x-coordinates, to which z-values are assigned to, are presetted to a the length of the z-cols respectively z-rows. But in my datasets at least one of theme is variable, so I am assigning z-values to defined timesteps (x-coordinates) and variable positions (each timestep differs from the other, y-coordinate). This is´nt included in my example here yet, because the errors are caused by another reason. If there is another solution than plotly I´m ready to work around at this. I´m slowly getting stuck with plotly and saving an image.. :(

> library(plotly)   zz <-
>   data.frame(c(0,0,0,0,0),c(0.1,.2,.4,.2,.1),c(0.2,.4,.8,.4,.2),c(0.1,.2,.4,.2,.1),c(0,0,0,0,0))
>   zz <- cbind(t(zz),rep(NA,length(zz[,1])))   xx <-
>   rep(seq(-1,1.5,.5),5)   print(plot_ly(z=zz,x=xx, type="surface"))
>   if(requireNamespace("RSelenium")){
>   +   rD<-RSelenium::rsDriver(browser="chrome",port=4448L)
>   +   export(last_plot(),"plot.png",rD)
>   + }   checking Selenium Server versions:   BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD   BEGIN: DOWNLOAD   BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD   checking chromedriver versions:
>   BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD   BEGIN: DOWNLOAD   BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD   checking
>   geckodriver versions:   BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD   BEGIN: DOWNLOAD   BEGIN:
>   POSTDOWNLOAD   checking phantomjs versions:   BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
>   BEGIN: DOWNLOAD   BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
>
> [1] "Connecting to remote server"   $applicationCacheEnabled [1] FALSE
>
> $rotatable [1] FALSE
>
> $mobileEmulationEnabled [1] FALSE
>
> $networkConnectionEnabled [1] FALSE
>
> $chrome $chrome$chromedriverVersion [1] "2.34.522940
>   (1a76f96f66e3ca7b8e57d503b4dd3bccfba87af1)"
>
> $chrome$userDataDir [1] "C:\Users\"MY
>   USERNAME"\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir4944_16134"
>
> $takesHeapSnapshot [1] TRUE
>
> $pageLoadStrategy [1] "normal"
>
> $databaseEnabled [1] FALSE
>
> $handlesAlerts [1] TRUE
>
> $hasTouchScreen [1] FALSE
>
> $version [1] "62.0.3202.94"
>
> $platform [1] "Windows NT"
>
> $browserConnectionEnabled [1] FALSE
>
> $nativeEvents [1] TRUE
>
> $acceptSslCerts [1] TRUE
>
> $locationContextEnabled [1] TRUE
>
> $webStorageEnabled [1] TRUE
>
> $browserName [1] "chrome"
>
> $takesScreenshot [1] TRUE
>
> $javascriptEnabled [1] TRUE
>
> $cssSelectorsEnabled [1] TRUE
>
> $setWindowRect [1] TRUE
>
> $unexpectedAlertBehaviour [1] ""
>
> $id [1] "773ac2fc888a773c98c926fe082961a3"
>
> Hide Traceback    Rerun with Debug    Error in
>   as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) :      cannot coerce
>   class "c("rsClientServer", "environment")" to a data.frame
>   6.   stop(gettextf("cannot coerce class \"%s\" to a data.frame", deparse(class(x))),
>       domain = NA)
>   5.   as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE)
>   4.   as.data.frame(x[[i]], optional = TRUE)
>   3.   data.frame(url = url, file = file, vwidth = vwidth, vheight = vheight)
>   2.   webshot::webshot(f, file, ...)
>   1.   export(last_plot(), "plot.png", rD)